# GIT: How do I add a file to the first commit (and rewrite history in the process)?

Tags: git

I'd like to add one file to git repository as if it was there from the start. I only found explanations how to remove a file from entire history, not how to add one.

I tried `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git add LICENSE.txt'` but I got error that the file can't be found.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`git filter-branch` *can* do this but is probably a lot heavier weight than needed.

How big and branch-y is your history?  If it's small and short, the easiest way to do this would be add the new file now, then use `git rebase -i --root` to move the new commit to the 2nd position and squash it into the root commit.

For instance, let's say you have:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
* e8719c9 (HEAD, master) umlaut
* b615ade finish
* e743479 initial
```

(your SHA-1 values will differ of course) and you want to add `LICENSE.txt` (already in the work dir) to the tree as part of the root commit.  You can just do it now:

```
$ git add LICENSE.txt && git commit -m 'add LICENSE, for fixup into root'
[master 924ccd9] add LICENSE, for fixup into root
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 LICENSE.txt
```

then run `git rebase -i --root`.  Grab the last line (`pick ... add LICENSE, ...`) and move it to the second line, changing `pick` to `fixup`, and write the rebase-commands file out and exit the editor:

```
".git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo" 22L, 705C written
[detached HEAD 7273593] initial
 2 files changed, 4 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 LICENSE.txt
 create mode 100644 x.txt
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
```

The (new, completely-rewritten) history now looks more like this:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
* bb71dde (HEAD, master) umlaut
* 7785112 finish
* 7273593 initial
```

and `LICENSE.txt` is in all commits.

---

If you do have a more complicated (branchy) history and want to use `git filter-branch` to get it all updated, the `--tree-filter` you need is not:

```
'git add LICENSE.txt'
```

but rather:

```
'cp /somewhere/outside/the/repo/LICENSE.txt LICENSE.txt'
```

to copy the new file into the tree each time.  (A faster method would be to use the `--index-filter` but this is more complex.)

Answer (score 13):

`--index-filter` provides a simple and fast solution:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "cp /abs/path/to/LICENSE.txt . && git add LICENSE.txt" --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty -- --all
```

---

Here is a very simple benchmark against other proposed methods.

The first column (`large`) shows the timings in seconds for one run of each filter in copies of the Git project repository (45885 commits, checkout of ~30M). The `rebase` method does not apply since it does not handle merges automatically, even with the `-c` option.

The second columns (`medium`) shows median times for three runs of each method in copies of a medium sized repository with a linear history and fairly large trees (2430 commits, checkout of ~80M).

The third column (`small`) shows median times for three runs of each method in copies of a small repository (554 commits, checkout of ~100K).

```
              large medium  small
index-filter   1064     38     10
tree-filter    4319     81     15
rebase            -    116     28
```

Also note that the `rebase` is not functionally equivalent to the `filter-branch` variants, as it updates the committer dates.

Comment: I tried your solution and it did well in my situation. But it seems that the new file only exists in the master branch. So I cherry-picked the different commits from other branches to build the rest branches and it worked. I don't think that it's a recommended way to solve this. So what's the correct way? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @walterlv To rewrite all branches just append `-- --all` to the command.

Comment: I've tried your arguments `-- --all` and it works for me. Thanks a lot! By the way, git docs said that the `--` seperated the path and revisions.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    --tree-filter <command>
>        This is the filter for rewriting the tree and its contents. The
>        argument is evaluated in shell with the working directory set to
>        the root of the checked out tree. The new tree is then used as-is
>        (new files are auto-added, disappeared files are auto-removed -
>        neither .gitignore files nor any other ignore rules HAVE ANY
>        EFFECT!).
> ```

Note that you start in a fresh checkout of each version.  So the command you want is something like `--tree-filter 'cp $HOME/LICENSE.txt .'`  I like torek's answer better (using `rebase`) unless you have so many revisions that it is impractical.