# git: recover older version of a file as new file, keeping history

Tags: git, diff, commit

I have a Java class file, say `JavaClass.java`, that has a commit history, like this:

```
01/01/2020 Commit1 JavaClass.java
...        ...     ...
01/01/2024 CommitN JavaClass.java
```

I want to recover an older version of the file and use it as a new file (with a new different name, of course), so that I can have both old and new file in the same branch, but **keeping all the commit history for both files** (i.e., something like splitting the file history), like this:

```
JavaClass.java         // file at CommitN, as it is modified by time
JavaClass_Renamed.java // file at Commit1, with a different name
```

Is it possible? I am trying various combinations of `git` commands but without success right now. For example, a `merge` between the old version of the file (renamed, in a new branch) and the current branch leads clearly to merge the two versions of the file, while I want the two versions to be separated.

Comment: The part about bringing out the state of JavaClass.java from an earlier commit and calling it JavaClass_Renamed.java is easy. The part about "keeping all the commit history for both files" seems like nonsense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I agree with the first part. For the second one, the reason between this is that I want to make new changes to that file, but I also want to keep track of the contributes of other users to that file (only bringing back the file and renaming would create a new file where the only contributor is me, deleting all the other people's commit history)

Comment: A file does not have a history in Git so what you're saying makes no sense. Commits have history in the sense that there is a parent chain. It sounds to me like you want is to rewrite history completely, making it seem that you had cleverly preserved the state of this file back at some earlier point. So do that. Instead of pulling the old file out now (i.e. into the top of the current branch), do an interactive rebase where you go back to the commit that has the state you want to preserve, create the renamed file as a copy of it, and continue the rebase.

Comment: However, this will not affect how Git "follows" the file backwards in time; nothing can really change that. The thing you are thinking of as "file history" is just an emergent property of logging; it isn't something stored in the repo.

Answer (score -1):

This task is easy, as long as you don't want to keep the history:

1. Make sure that you have a clean working directory by either committing uncommitted changes or by stashing them with `git stash`.
2. Check out the revision which you want to get the file from with `git checkout --detach 3738368fb` (while obviously replacing the commit hash with the hash that you want to check out).
3. Copy the file in question to another folder. You can also rename the file in that other location to the new file name.
4. Go back to where you started before with `git checkout main` and popping the stash if you created one earlier: `git stash pop`
5. Move the file from the other location back into the git repo.

Keeping the history is a whole different thing, though. You would need to change the commit history, which comes with its own caveats: If you pushed the commits some place else (like GitHub) and other people may have pulled the commits already, you need to coordinate a force-push with all those people. If you are working on a feature-branch, this will probably be ok, but if you are working on main, master or develop this will probably not be very easy as you would need to ensure that nobody else is committing or pushing anything to your branch, since their work would be overwritten by your history rewrite.

Most importantly, though, modifying the history will be very time-consuming with little to no benefit:

1. You could start an [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) and `edit` any commit that contains edits to that file.
2. You might also want to have a look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21353584/git-how-do-i-add-a-file-to-the-first-commit-and-rewrite-history-in-the-process) which discusses how to add a file to the git history, which is more or less what you want to do.